# Powershell variables in the command

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have this powershell command:
    $socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("10.1.2.3", "80")
This works great.

I would like to be able to enter the ip address & port number at the command line and have that go in to the ps command. Hopefully makes sense...

If this was an old batch file it would be the equal of %1 and %2, but I'm not understanding how to do that with powershell.

Thanks, Jon

Comment: What have you tried? Like you say, variables in PS are easy-peasy. Also a note: "cmd" and "command" generally refer to the command prompt in Windows, which is not PowerShell. It can be confusing when you use these terms in relation to PS and in particular to what you have here. You appear to be putting together a script of some sort, not a "command".

Comment: Why don't you use [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566052/how-to-check-network-port-access-and-display-useful-message) ***your*** line presumably stems from?

Comment: First you show a line that does work. Then you show an example (incorrectly formatted) of calling a function with parameters. But you haven’t shown us a function and the one liner you started with is not a function. Strip the code down to its basics to learn with and post all of it. It’s hard to say where you’re going wrong, if not multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with... 
Powershell script to check a port open or not...like telnet ... but quicker
if prompt returns with no detail, port is open. Otherwise, big error is thrown.

1-    PSChkPort.ps1 file will be this:
$socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($args[0], $args[1])

2-    PSTel.bat batch file will be this:
powershell -file PSChkPort.ps1 %1 %2
3- Run the batch file with these parameters: PSTel.bat 10.1.1.1 1433